# Use @ symbol as variable in if statement in Excel

Tags: excel, filter

I'm keeping track of sports stats in a league and would like to be able to sort results according to whether a team was playing at home or away. My spreadsheet is set up so that each team has its own column with its name on top and results below with various stats in between (average, standard deviation etc.) On the lefthand side of this column (where the results are) is another column with @ symbols to mark away games. I would like to use this symbol (and absence of symbol) to create home/away statistics (as opposed to simply compiling both away and home games in a single cell). The formula I have in mind would look like this

// If result is preceded by @ symbol, apply to formula here, if not, apply to formula there.

Please have a look at the example (using std. dev.) to better understand my question.

[image]

Comment: I cannot open you sample file at work. But it sounds like one of the `COUNTIF`, `SUMIF` formulas and their plural versions might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an IF function as shown below.

```
    {=SUM(IF(A5:A8="@",B5:B8))}
```

Where column "A" has (or doesn't have) your "@" sign and column "B" is your data.

So you would do your math against what is inside the "IF" statement. For the data without the "@" sign you would use "" instead of "@".
Two key things:
1. There's no need for a result for "value_if_false" in the "IF" statement, so you can leave it out.
2. This has to be entered as an array formula, so instead of just enter, you have to do ctrl-shift-enter. That will put the curly brackets around it; "{" and "}".